# Create New Database user to login to SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please see the T-SQL below:

```
create database db;
go

use [db]

create login [standard] with password ='dkdkdkqajHGgbh56'
CREATE USER [standard] FROM LOGIN [standard];

exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'standard'
```

After running this I try to login to SQL Server Management Studio as `standard` and I am prompted with this error:

> login failed for user: standard

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I cannot even login as sa. I have enabled 'SQL Server Windows Authentication mode'. I am a developer (not a DBA) trying to setup a local instance of SQL Server.

Comment: Can you verify your authentication mode using `SELECT CASE SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')   
WHEN 1 THEN 'Windows Authentication'   
WHEN 0 THEN 'Windows and SQL Server Authentication'   
END as [Authentication Mode]  `. SA is disabled by default so it's not expected to work out of the box.

Comment: When you use the Connect to Server box to connect, what is in the Authentication box? Is it "Windows Authentication" or "SQL Server Authentication"?

Answer (score 2):

I had to enable: 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode', then restart the SQL Server 2012 service.